# Laravel "page" query string parameter ignored in API when trying to use pagination

Tags: php, laravel

I have this endpoint where I want to utilize pagination:

```php
public function list() {
    return Cache::remember('list_albums_'.App::getLocale(), 60, function () {
        return Album::with(['group', 'event', 'event.translation'])
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->simplePaginate(12);
    });
}
```

However, the same 12 results are always returned. The network request shows that `?page=X` is being sent, but the response is always identical.

Route:

```php
Route::get('/albums/{page?}', 'AlbumController@list');
```

Comment: With Laravel's pagination, `page` needs to be a Query String parameter, like `/albums?page=1`, not a URL Parameter like `/albums/1` (your code looks like it's doing that, but you don't need `/{page?}` parameter on your Route; it's redundant and not being used)

Comment: Also if you're caching, you're probably always going to get the same results unless you update your caching.

Comment: @TimLewis Ah ok! Can I utilize the page query param in the cache name somehow? i.e. append it to 'list_albums_'.App::getLocale()?

Comment: Hmm... That's a great question actually; this isn't something I've ever tried to do before  Caching individual pagination pages seems like it would generate a _lot_ of cached results, bloating quickly. Pagination is already designed to speed up retrieval of large data Collections, so I would be tempted to say ditch it, especially if you're only paginating 12 results at a time. With like 100s it could make more sense. You can definitely give it a try; appending the value of `?page=X` to your Cache Key _would_ "bust" it as required, but seems like overkill 

Comment: @TimLewis Makes sense! I'll remove the caching since we only get a total of about 20 album entries per year, and we only show 12 at a time.

Comment: @TimLewis anyway, the solution was to remove caching. Answer the question and I will mark it if you want :) Thank you!

Comment: Sweet! And sounds good; I'll adjust my comment to an answer. Cheers 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Laravel's caching, even if the contained code is reactive to the parameters being passed, such as Laravel's Pagination automatically paging based on the including of `?page=X`, Caching will override that, unless the cache is "Busted" (i.e. by using a unique Cache Key, such as `'list_albums_' . App::getLocale() . request()->input('page')`).

Since Pagination is already designed as a method to improve loading by "chunking" results into smaller portions, doubling-up on Caching, which is designed to increase loading times by not having to reload things *can* be redundant, especially for small page sizes like 12. For 100s or 1000s of results, tacking on this `request()->input('page')` would make sense, but for 12, it would just end up bloating your cache.

In this instance, it's probably best to simply remove caching, and allow Pagination to work natively. Also, your Route Parameter is redundant, and is not actually being used, so you can remove that too:

`routes/web.php` (or `api.php`, etc.)

```
Route::get('/albums', 'AlbumController@list');
```

`AlbumController.php`:

```
public function list() {
  return Album::with(['group', 'event', 'event.translation'])
  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
  ->simplePaginate(12);
}
```